# Relativistic Analytical Mechanics of Ponderomotive Equations per Bergmann

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, hamiltonian-formalism

The following is based on Peter Gabrial Bergmann's Introduction to
the Theory of Relativity, pages 117 and 118.

$A_{s}$ are the components of the electromagnetic 3-vector potential.

The components of the electric field are $E_{s}=-\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial A_{s}}{\partial t}-\phi_{,s}$
and the magnetic field tensor components are$H_{rs}=A_{s,r}-A_{r,s}$.

I established this expression for the time derivative of the vector
potential in order to carry out the subsequent derivations

$\dot{A_{s}}=\frac{\partial A_{s}}{\partial t}+u^{r}A_{s,r}$.

The Lagrangian

$L=-mc^{2}\sqrt{1-u^{2}/c^{2}}-{\scriptstyle e}\phi+\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}u^{s}A_{s}$

is given. The momentum components are defined by

$p_{s}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial u^{s}}=\frac{mu^{s}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}/c^{2}}}+\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}A_{s}$.

From the variational principle we have

$\dot{p}_{s}-L_{,s}=0$.

The time derivative of a momentum component is

$\dot{p}_{s}=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{mu^{s}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}/c^{2}}}\right]+\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}\left(\frac{\partial A_{s}}{\partial t}+u^{r}A_{s,r}\right)$.

The partial of the Lagrangian with respect to a space coordinate is

$L_{,s}=-{\scriptstyle e}\phi_{,s}+\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}u^{r}A_{r,s}$.

Note that I assumed $u_{,s}^{r}=0$.

Putting these together and manipulating the result I get the following:

$\dot{p}_{s}-L_{,s}=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{mu^{s}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}/c^{2}}}\right]+\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}\left(\frac{\partial A_{s}}{\partial t}+u^{r}A_{s,r}-u^{r}A_{r,s}\right)+{\scriptstyle e}\phi_{,s}$

$=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{mu^{s}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}/c^{2}}}\right]+\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}u^{r}\left(A_{s,r}-A_{r,s}\right)+{\scriptstyle e}\left(\frac{{\scriptstyle 1}}{c}\frac{\partial A_{s}}{\partial t}+\phi_{,s}\right)$

$=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{mu^{s}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}/c^{2}}}\right]+\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}u^{r}H_{rs}-{\scriptstyle e}E_{s}$

$\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{mu^{s}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}/c^{2}}}\right]=\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}u^{r}H_{sr}+{\scriptstyle e}E_{s}$

Which, by happy coincidence, is what Bergmann gives as the Euler-Lagrange
equations for the given Lagrangian.

Bergmann also rewrites the Lagrangian treating $u^{s}$ as a function
of $p_{s}$ and $A_{s}$. Solving the following for $u^{s}$

$p_{s}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial u^{s}}=\frac{mu^{s}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}/c^{2}}}+\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}A_{s}$

results in

$u^{s}=\frac{1}{m}\left(p_{s}-\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}A_{s}\right)\left[1+\frac{\left(p_{k}-\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}A_{k}\right)^{2}}{m^{2}c^{2}}\right]^{-1/2}$.

Evidently $\left(p_{k}-\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}A_{k}\right)^{2}=\left(p_{j}-\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}A_{j}\right)\left(p_{k}-\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}A_{k}\right)\delta^{jk}$,
though Bergmann never stated as much explicitly.

Further manipulations result in a Hamiltonian of the form

$H=mc^{2}\left[1+\frac{\left(p_{k}-\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}A_{k}\right)^{2}}{m^{2}c^{2}}\right]^{1/2}+{\scriptstyle e}\phi$.

Using this, Bergmann gets (summation on k intended)

$\dot{p}_{s}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x^{s}}=\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{mc}\left[1+\frac{\left(p_{l}-\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}A_{l}\right)^{2}}{m^{2}c^{2}}\right]^{-1/2}\left(p_{k}-\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}A_{k}\right)A_{k,s}-{\scriptstyle e}\phi_{,s}$

Now my confusion comes about when I observe that

$p_{s}-\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}A_{s}=\frac{mu^{s}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}/c^{2}}}$

So that

$\frac{1}{m}\left(p_{s}-\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}A_{s}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}/c^{2}}=u^{s}=\frac{1}{m}\left(p_{s}-\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}A_{s}\right)\left[1+\frac{\left(p_{k}-\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}A_{k}\right)^{2}}{m^{2}c^{2}}\right]^{-1/2}$

And, therefore

$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}/c^{2}}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{\left(p_{k}-\frac{{\scriptstyle e}}{c}A_{k}\right)^{2}}{m^{2}c^{2}}}$.

If my assumption that $u_{,s}^{r}=0$ were valid for the Hamiltonian,
then

$\dot{p}_{s}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x^{s}}=-mc^{2}\gamma_{,s}-{\scriptstyle e}\phi_{,s}=-{\scriptstyle e}\phi_{,s}$

Which is clearly not the same result.  Was I wrong to treat velocity as independent of position in the first derivation?  If not, at what point does that assumption become invalid?

Comment: This may help motivate a qualified observer to give this topic consideration.  Quoted from the forward of Bergmann's book: "Much effort has gone into making this book logically and pedagogically satisfactory, and Dr. Bergmann has spent many hours with me 
which were devoted to this end. It is my hope that many students 
will enjoy the book and gain from it a better understanding of the accomplishments and problems of modern theoretical physics. 

A. Einstein 
The Institute for Advanced Study "

Comment: I believe I have the answer, but I am not positive. The velocity should be treated as a function of position.  What Bergmann gives as the Euler-Lagrange equations (EOM) for the stated Lagrangian is a definition, not a derived result. Applying the chain rule, derivative of the Lagrangian includes a term which is the contraction of relativistic momentum with the gradient of velocity.  Because this must be consistent with the EOM, that term must vanish.  This indicates that the true velocity must be in the direction of a stationary value, where the gradient vanishes.